# CSV identity fields: nHibernate oddity or db design error?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, database-design

I've inherited a database and know an nHibernate engine was used on top of it.

Inside the database I see CSV values representing multiple identities instead of "proper" link tables being used for primary and foreign keys.

For example one tuple looks like this:

> **PersonID**, int: **1**
>   **Name**, varchar: **John Smith**
>   **Edus**, varchar: "**76,5262,5261,5263,5264"**
>   **Events**, varchar: **"533,568,538,548,567,572"**
>   **Email**, varchar: **jsmith@example.com**

I'm curious if this is a feature of Hibernate (possibly a way to configure it) or just questionable relational database design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate does not directly support anything like that, so you'll have to look at the rest of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the source code for the system, only the resulting db; however it's good to have my curiosity satisfied about the nHibernate engine.

Comment: In that case, you can be sure that NH does not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Questionable database design.
This is called *repeating groups*.
It violates [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).